# Getting Data from an html on Xcode

Tags: html, xcode, parsing, xcode10

I know how to take the html as a string from a website and the basics of parsing. Can anyone help with a more complicated html like this website:

https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/markus-howard-1/gamelog/

I want to know how get stats from a specific game

Answer (score 0):

What language are you working with?

There isn't much information to go on here, but you might want to look into the Unix cURL utility, which should be available from the MacOS (I'm assuming) Terminal.

Here is a Wikipedia page on cURL:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.